# Arabic letters not showing correctly on website

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, wamp, arabic

i'm developing a website that contains both english and arabic languages and running on **WAMP server**. it used to show arabic letters just fine but suddenly it started showing arabic chars as weird symbols like: Ø­Ù…Ø¯Ù…Ø­Ù…Ø¯

Here's somethings i noticed about the issue:

- The issue is only happening on **chrome browser**, firefox and IE showing arabic perfectly.
- The issue is showing in only some pages, the other are working okay. although i have the utf8 meta tag in all the pages: `<meta charset="UTF-8">`.

  - I tried restarting WAMP but the issue persist.